# wxWidgets library settings

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

[image]

How can one find out the installed library settings of wxWidgets?

Or how can one solve a problem such as the one shown in the image?

Comment: I presume you just downloaded a prebuilt binaries from the official web site?

Answer (score 2):

The debug builds of the library will have a "d" suffix in their names under MSW, e.g. `wxmsw30ud_core.lib` is the debug version of the core library while `wxmsw30u_core.lib` is the release version (note the missing "d").

To solve your problem, you should build, or download, the debug builds of the libraries too. How to do this exactly depends on how/where did you get the release builds.